# Слова "бог", "боги", "божество", "божества"

Tags: этимология, лексика, морфология, выбор-слов, синонимы

**1.** В русском языке есть собирательные имена существительные: человечество, купечество, крестьянство, офицерство, казачество, студенчество.

**Вопрос 1**: Верно ли, что слово "божество" было и/или является собирательным именем существительным?

**2.** В русском языке есть слова "цветок", "цветки", "соцветие", "соцветия".

**Вопрос 2**: Верно ли, что слово "соцветие" было и/или является собирательным именем существительным?

**3.** В русском языке есть собирательные имена существительные: казачество, генералитет, вороньё, листва, ...

**Вопрос 3**: Верно ли, что предложение "Собирательными называются существительные, обозначающие как целое все объекты какого-то множества." равносильно предложению "Каждое собирательное имя существительное есть наименование какого-то множества."?

**4.** Предположим, что слово "бог" и слово "божество" являются синонимами.

**Вопрос 4**: Верно ли, что в сознании русскоязычного атеиста слово "божество" идентично слову " " (пустому слову)?

Answer (score 4):

> Верно ли, что слово "божество" было и/или является собирательным именем  существительным?

Нет.

> Верно ли, что слово "соцветие" было и/или является собирательным именем существительным?

Нет.

Собирательными называются существительные, обозначающие как целое все объекты какого-то множества. Казачество — все казаки, студенчество - все студенты и т. д. Ни «соцветие», ни тем более «божество» такого смысла не несут.

В случае «божества» Вы пошли по пути сопоставления внешней формы слова и забыли про смысл. Во втором случае даже не могу предположить, чем могло быть вызвано подобное предположение. Соцветие никак не просто все цветы, это самостоятельный объект.

Кстати, собирательные существительные никогда не имеют формы множественного числа, что для рассматриваемых слов тоже неверно.

Есть, правда, в дополнение к сказанному несколько так называемых «счетных собирательных» существительных — сотня (бойцов), например — но это тем более не наш случай.

> Вопрос 3: Верно ли, что предложение "Собирательными называются существительные, обозначающие как целое все объекты какого-то множества", равносильно предложению "Каждое собирательное имя существительное есть наименование какого-то множества"?

Глубоко неверно.

1. Утверждение «В огороде бузина» не равносильно «В Киеве — дядька».  Равносильными называются утверждения, каждое из которых является следствием другого.
2. Первое из второго вообще никак не следует, второе из  первого — только с многочисленными оговорками о значении слов «множество» и «наименование». А если подумать, что в формулировке может быть заложено ещё и различие значений слов «называется», «считается», «обозначает» и т. д., да ещё есть немаловажный момент «как единого целого» — и ни то, ни другое никакой формальной логикой не поймаешь. Продолжать не имеет смысла.
3. С подобными вопросами извольте на математику.

Comment: 1. Принял к сведению Ваше мнение по первым трём вопросам.

2. Если мои вопросы вызывают у Вас раздражение (а это очень заметно), тогда попытайтесь не отвечать на мои вопросы.

Comment: Точно, @behemothus, этот персонаж уже достал всех на Математике. Не отвечайте.

Answer (score 2):

БОЖЕСТВО 'бог', 'нечто божественное'. Заимствовано из ст.-сл. языка. Ст.-сл. **божьство** 'божественное естество' является калькой греч. theotos 'божественность, божество', производного от theos 'бог'. От сущ. *божьство* с пом. суф. -ьи- образовано прилагательное божьствьныи > соврем. божественный 'божеский' (церк.) и 'прекрасный, дивный, бесподобный'. (По данным словаря Цыганенко). О собирательности речи нет.

Comment: Верно ли я понял, что слово "божество" не было и не является собирательным именем существительным?

Comment: Думаю, это и имелось в виду в последнем предложении, так что вы всё верно поняли.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 0):

> Берешит бара Элохим эта шамаим ветха рец.

Первая фраза Ветхого завета.

Вначале Боги сотворил небеса и землю, переводят теологи.
Имя Элохим состоит из двух частей: приставка святости"Ал" и название созвездия "Хим" - семь звёзд созвездия Плеяда (то есть Семья).
Надеюсь информация полезна для продолжения размышлений.